# Disable ParameterValidation in MWAA Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, mwaa

In MWAA, I am using the following code to access the files in my S3 bucket. The S3 bucket is of the following form:

```
aws s3 ls s3://example-bucket/incoming/driver-events/ingestDate=2021-05-26/
```

The above command works fine. Now I am attempting to get the same information from an `S3_hook.S3Hook()` call from Airflow. I have the following code:

```
bucket='s3://example-bucket/incoming/driver-events/ingestDate=2021-05-26/'
s3_handle = S3_hook.S3Hook(aws_conn_id='s3_default')
        key_list = s3_handle.list_keys(bucket_name=bucket)
        print(f"{len(key_list)} keys found in bucket")
        for keys in key_list:
            logging.info(keys)
```

This is resulting in an error from boto3:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "s3://example-bucket/incoming/driver-events/ingestDate=2021-05-26/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

I can understand that the error is coming because boto3 is attempting to do some parameter validation and the regular expression is too restrictive.

How do I handle this case in Airflow? Is there any way I can disable the parameter validation? I can see that one can set 'parameter_validation' to `False` in boto3 through some configuration setting, but how do I do that when using an `S3Hook()` in Airflow that is already set up in its default way and cannot accept a boto3 configuration? And making it more complicated is that I have to do it on MWAA which does not give you any control over `~/.boto/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that bucket should only be `example-bucket` and the path should be the `prefix` provided to the function call to list objects. S3 does not store the data as folders and files, instead they are all key-value pairs. Thus the key is the full directory structure of the path.

The code block that works is as follows:

```
bucket_prefix = 'incoming/driver-events/ingestDate=2021-05-26/'
client = boto3.client('s3', 
        aws_access_key_id=Variable.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), 
        aws_secret_access_key=Variable.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
        response = client.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket='example-bucket',
            Delimiter='/',
            Prefix=bucket_prefix,
            MaxKeys=1000,
        )
        print(response)
        contents = response["Contents"]  # These are the files
        common_prefixes = response["CommonPrefixes"] # These are the folders
```